# Adding Authentication to Routes

Tags: php, laravel

I want to add authentication to my routes, I already had logins set up and I belive it is functional but you can still access everything on my website even if not logged in, I would like the website to open on the '/welcome' view as this has the login button. Once a user logs in be brought to the '/' view. Any ideas how I would do this?

```
Route::get('/bookingforms/create/{requestID}', 'RequestFormsController@getPatientData');

Route::get('/completes/create/{bookingID}', 'BookingFormsController@getCompleteData');
Route::get('/incompletes/create/{bookingID}', 'BookingFormsController@getIncompleteData');

Route::post('/bookingform/submit', 'BookingFormsController@submit');

Route::get('/bookings', 'BookingFormsController@getBookings');

Route::get('/requestform', 'PagesController@getRequestForm');

Route::get('/waitinglist', 'RequestFormsController@getWaitingLists');

Route::post('/requestform/submit', 'RequestFormsController@submit');



Route::resource('requestforms', 'RequestFormsController' );
Route::resource('bookingforms', 'BookingFormsController');
Route::resource('completes', 'CompletesController');
Route::resource('incompletes', 'IncompletesController');



Route::get('/', 'PagesController@getHome');

Route::get('/about', 'PagesController@getAbout');

Route::get('/contact', 'PagesController@getContact');

Route::get('/welcome', 'PagesController@getWelcome');

Route::get('/login', 'LoginController@getLogin');

Route::get('/messages', 'MessagesController@getMessages');

Route::post('/contact/submit', 'MessagesController@submit');

Route::get('/register', 'RegisterController@getRegister');

Route::get('/logout', 'LoginController@logout');




Auth::routes();
Route::get('/', 'PagesController@getHome');
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');

  Route::prefix('admin')->group(function() {
    Route::get('/login', 'Auth\AdminLoginController@showLoginForm')->name('admin.login');
    Route::post('/login', 'Auth\AdminLoginController@login')->name('admin.login.submit');
    Route::get('/', 'AdminController@index')->name('admin.dashboard');
    Route::get('/messages', 'AdminController@index')->name('admin.messages');
  });
```

Comment: it's your api.php or web.php of your project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can either group your routes under the auth middleware like this:

```
Route::middleware(['auth'])->group(function () {
    // your protected routes goes here
});
```

or protect each route individually in the controller's constructor like this:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

aside: why are you defining auth routes twice?

Comment: The group one worked for me thank you so much!! I have removed the duplicates now, forgot some of them were still there as I had redone parts of my wesbite! Many thanks for your help :)

Comment: Could I use the same thing for Admin Routes?

Comment: you already have a group for the admin, just add the middleware part.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the default Auth from Laravel?

If so, check the documentation https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication#protecting-routes

Other wise you will have to create a middleware to check the login session and if the user is not logged return redirect to a url.

Answer (score 0):

I would make a route for logins. Have it be a post so you can store the logins in your database. Then on a successful login you can pass the user a JSON webtoken. Have the client store that webtoken.

Then you can add an authentication middleware, and insert it into the pipeline before the request gets pushed to your endpoint. Have the user pass the webtoken and decrypt it in the auth middleware. If it’s successful pass the user on to the end point otherwise return a response and terminate the request.

Middleware is vital for authentication, authorization, and you can add a middleware to the end of your pipeline to check for errors as well.

If you need more than the abstract let me know and I’ll find some examples for you.